# rails metasearch sort by nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, meta-search

Can you sort by nested resource with metasearch?

normally, `item.customer_id`

so sort would be `<%= sort_link @search, :customer_id %>`

but would like to sort by the `customer.first_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= sort_link @search, :customer_first_name %>
```

should work

Comment: tried it and it didn't work :(.  Guess I would have to create a scope for it?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that part; sorry about that

`scope :sort_by_customer_first_name_asc, order('custom_name ASC')`
`scope :sort_by_customer_first_name_desc, order('custom_name DESC')`

Comment: Don't know why, but all of a sudden it started working after a restart.  Both your answer and the scope method worked.  Thanks!